# Calling foreign phone number that happens to be in the same country

Tags: cellphones

I am French but currently living in the US. I have a French cell phone number (+33XXXXXXXXX).

Would someone calling me from the US be charged an international call (the +33 prefix being more important than the actual geographical location of the phone)?

Comment: The carrier that your contract is with can answer that.  We don’t even know who that is, much less what is in that contract.

Comment: The question isn't perfectly clear, but if you are asking what a US caller will be charged to call your French cell phone number then they will be charged whatever their plan charges to call a French cell phone number. It doesn't matter where the French cell phone is, the +33 number they dial determines their charge.

Comment: Thank you Dennis, that answers my question (whever the +33 prefix matters more than my geographical location). I tried to rewrite the question to make it clearer, don't hesitate to post your answer so that I can validate it.

Comment: They will indeed be charged for a call to a French mobile number, **and** you will be charged for receiving a call while roaming.

Comment: If you are connected to WiFi, via local networks the easiest way to get around this is to ask folks to call you on a platform like WhatsApp, or Skype. Then you aren't actually using the telephone network, unless you are data roaming which is a bad idea internationally. Some providers, also provide SIP connectivity for mobile users. If you were one of those lucky people, you may find a direct SIP call would not cost you extra, the US caller would still be calling a foreign phone though so they would be charged unless it was a purely SIP-SIP call, which might be free. You may have options.